# Does the article "the" needs to be used every time in a paragraph while mentioning something that has been referred earlier?

Tags: articles, paragraphs

I not a native English speaker and have real difficulties in the usage of articles in paragraphs, especially the use of article `the'. For instance kindly consider the following paragraph:

> In Fig. 11, we have given both analytical and simulated results. The
>   analytical results are plotted using (4). On the other hand, for the
>   simulation results, we have done numerical simulations. Furthermore,
>   for the analytical results, we have approximated T by the discrete
>   parameter t. It can be seen from the figure that the analytical
>   results match well with the simulated ones for most of the illustrated
>   range. However, the tail probabilities of the analytical results do
>   not offer such a nice matching with the simulated results.

Now I am just concerned with the usage of "the" with the words analytical and simulated. Do "the" needs to accompany the words simulated and analytical results every time they are used in the paragraph after the first reference? Or I can omit "the" sometimes? If yes then where and what is the logic of doing so? I have been told that my usage of "the" is quite arbitrary, so need help.

Please also refer to Ram Pillai comment where the aesthetics of the sentence is being referred to. It has been pointed out that in the sentence:

```
It can be seen from the figure that the analytical results match well with the simulated ones for most of the illustrated range.
```

'the' is used four times.

Comment: Yes, you need the definite articles to clarify that you're still talking about all the set you first mentioned. Consider << They received a sum of money from their sponsors. Money was spent on improving facilities. >> vs << They received a sum of money from their sponsors. The money was spent on improving facilities. >>

Comment: If you remove usages of *the* later in the paragraph because you think they sound repetitive, this will definitely give the impression to your readers that your usage of "the" is arbitrary.

Comment: The article is associated with "results", not "analytical" or "simulated".

Comment: If we stick to the rules of using 'the', we will see the scope for using it in many places. That will confuse the writer/reader whether all these 'the's are required or not. E.g., in the OP's example, "It can be seen from the figure that the analytical results match well with the simulated ones for most of the illustrated range" where the is used four times. It affects the aesthetics of sentence making.

Comment: @ Ram Pillai This is the issue, I am totally confused as to where to use "the" and where not, so that 'the' does not get repetitive. Figure is referred earlier so 'the' has to be there, same reasoning goes with the use of `the' with analytical and simulated results too. Can you help me a little bit further.

Comment: 'The' must be used wherever it is needed; it is exempt from the 'don't keep using the same word' mantra for lexical (as opposed to function) words. But 'wherever it is needed' takes decades to master.

Comment: //(The) Integrated risks are shown in Figure XYA.  (The) Population affected by flood was estimated. (The) Studies having been done, events were forecast for land use and population of the city.// This material was edited to delete 'the' in brackets given in the original text. If we stick to the strict rule, it will read like "//The integrated risks are shown in the Figure XYA.  The population affected by the flood was estimated. The studies having been done, the events were forecast for the land use and the population of the city.  Contd...

Comment: I think, 'the' should be used where reasonable emphasis needs to be given.  Even in journal material, we should think of the beauty part too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you are talking about your specific analytical results, you should use the definite article.  If you are talking about some other analytical results, or some abstract analytical results in-general, you should not.  Here's a contrasting example that refers to some results in-general

> We have given both analytical and simulated results. *The analytical results* are plotted using lines.  *Analytical results* are usually a result of X algorithm, but *these analytical results* are a result of the new Y analysis algorithm.

Or for a specific other set of analytical results

> We have given both analytical and simulated results. *The analytical results* have a standard deviation of 1.2.  *Analytical results from Harvard's team* generally have a standard deviation of 3.4 - 5.6, because those jerks can't measure as precisely as our team.  *Those analytical results* are less reliable than *the analytical results in this paper.*

Dropping "the" (or "these") implies a different scope or meaning.  Use consistent usage while you are referring to consistent results.